# Using Python 3.4 and Beautiful Soup to handle Ajax Pagination

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is my first try at python and asking a question here, so i apologise for any incorrect structure of this question in advance.

The following code is working perfectly well.

The issue I'm having is that the script below scrapes the first page, however I can't work out, how to get the code to fire the Next Button, so that I can loop through that data and so on.

In the browser when you click the Next button the url remains the same, however the data in the table has refreshed with the appropriate result.

So i have assumed that the site is using ajax to refill the table.

Therefore my question is how do I programatically get python to set ajax off to refill the table with the next lot of data ?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime


# this crawls the url below for Primary and Secondary Schools throughout Australia
# and returns the Index(as a href link) for the details from the Href Link in the Index Output

# get the current date Time for the file labels
f_date = format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
# set the Index File Name
index_file_title = ('education_primary_secondary_index_' + f_date + '.csv')
index_error_file_title = ('education_primary_secondary_index_errors_' + f_date + '.csv')
f_index = open(index_file_title, 'w')
f_index_errors = open(index_error_file_title, 'w')


def education_primary_secondary_index_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    url = "http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php"
    striped_url = "http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au"
    while page <= max_pages:
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        #plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, "html.parser")
        for school_index_links in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'clearfix'}):
            try:
                school_index_href = striped_url + school_index_links.get('href')
                f_index.write(str(school_index_href) + '\n')
            except Exception as e:
                f_index_errors.write(str(page) + '-----' + str(e) + '\n')
                pass
                # call to Details Module
                #education_primary_secondary_details_spider(index_href)
        page += 1

education_primary_secondary_index_spider(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Next button casts POST request to http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php with Form Data that has "pageNum: 2". You can check this with opening dev console of your browser(F12 in chrome and firefox), go to network tab and start recording before clicking next.

And as I`m too lazy to find out what exactly needs to be in request to be valid for a server, I usually copy whole request as a curl, and convert it to requests request with: http://curl.trillworks.com/
So this will get you text of x page:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,cs;q=0.6',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}
x = 2
data = 'searchType=&Boarding=&Special=&Alternative=&Religion=&noRefine=&schoolName=&distanceCalc=&searchWithin=&list_state=&list_state2=&school_id=&search=true&pageNum=' + x + '&searchType=&specialNeeds=&alternative=&religion=&type=&level=&gender=&flashfile=&feature=&list_region=&list_subreg=&list_subreg2='

r = requests.post('http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have figured it out, I loaded selenium and within about 3 lines of code , got the job done.

Comment: Yeah selenium is another option, probably slower, but easier to code :)